# Is there a spefic way to read only the urls from a json file with python3?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to collect the links from the google history and past their content to .txt files. All the code works (when I created a json which contains only urls), but when the links are there as in the Source example, then I get the error mentioned below. I suspect it's because of the “ in the source data, but how can I get it to just read the URL part?

Source Data:

````
{
    "Browser History": [
        {
            "favicon_url": "https://www.google.com/favicon.ico",
            "page_transition": "LINK",
            "title": "Google Datenexport",
            "url": "https://takeout.google.com/",
            "client_id": "cWD5MfDDekj1z9aA5VeCQQ\u003d\u003d",
            "time_usec": 1607693084782187
},
        {
            "favicon_url": "https://support.google.com/favicon.ico",
            "page_transition": "LINK",
            "title": "So laden Sie Ihre Google-Daten herunter - Google-Konto-Hilfe",
            "url": "https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?visit_id\u003d637432898341218017-3159218066\u0026hl\u003dde\u0026rd\u003d1",
            "client_id": "cWD5MfDDekj1z9aA5VeCQQ\u003d\u003d",
            "time_usec": 1607693036534748
},
        {
            "favicon_url": "https://www.google.com/favicon.ico",
            "page_transition": "LINK",
            "title": "Google \u2013 Meine Aktivitäten",
            "url": "https://myactivity.google.com/activitycontrols/webandapp?view\u003ditem",
            "client_id": "cWD5MfDDekj1z9aA5VeCQQ\u003d\u003d",
            "time_usec": 1607693013403569
},
        {
            "favicon_url": "https://www.com-magazin.de/favicon.ico",
            "page_transition": "LINK",
            "title": "Google-Suchverlauf herunterladen und deaktivieren - com! professional",
            "url": "https://www.com-magazin.de/news/google/google-suchverlauf-herunterladen-deaktivieren-928063.html#:~:text\u003dUm%20die%20eigenen%20Suchanfragen%20herunterzuladen,Nutzer%20den%20Eintrag%20%22Herunterladen%22.",
            "client_id": "cWD5MfDDekj1z9aA5VeCQQ\u003d\u003d",
            "time_usec": 1607692994577620
}```
````

The code I use at the moment:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from dhooks import Webhook, Embed
import json


def getHtml(url):
    global response
    ua = UserAgent()
    {'user-agent': ua.random}
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=10)
        response.raise_for_status()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return response.content


with open('urls.json', 'r') as history:
    json_data = history.read()
    data = json.loads(json_data)

    for block in data:
        print("scraping " + block["url"] + "...")
        html = getHtml(json_data)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "html5lib")
        text = soup.find_all(text=True)

        output = ''

        blacklist = [
            "style",
            "url",
            "404",
            "ngnix",
            "url"

        ]

        for t in text:
            if t.parent.name not in blacklist:
                output += '{} '.format(t)

        with open("{}.txt".format(i), "w") as out_fd:
            out_fd.write(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your Source Data looks something like that,

```
[{
            "page_transition": "LINK",
            "title": "Niedersachsen nimmt geplante Corona-Lockerungen für Silvester zurück",
            "url": "https://www.rnd.de/politik/niedersachsen-nimmt-geplante-corona-lockerungen-fur-silvester-zuruck-IEW2P4XT4M24ZFFZSX7ILE6JGM.html?outputType\u003damp\u0026utm_source\u003dupday\u0026utm_medium\u003dreferral",
            "client_id": "59VD9fg/2RVO1jSDxOwfxw\u003d\u003d",
            "time_usec": 1607593733981438
},{
            "page_transition": "LINK",
            "title": "Niedersachsen nimmt geplante Corona-Lockerungen für Silvester zurück",
            "url": "https://www.rnd.de/politik/niedersachsen-nimmt-geplante-corona-lockerungen-fur-silvester-zuruck-IEW2P4XT4M24ZFFZSX7ILE6JGM.html?outputType\u003damp\u0026utm_source\u003dupday\u0026utm_medium\u003dreferral",
            "client_id": "59VD9fg/2RVO1jSDxOwfxw\u003d\u003d",
            "time_usec": 1607593733981438
}, {
            "page_transition": "LINK",
            "title": "Niedersachsen nimmt geplante Corona-Lockerungen für Silvester zurück",
            "url": "https://www.rnd.de/politik/niedersachsen-nimmt-geplante-corona-lockerungen-fur-silvester-zuruck-IEW2P4XT4M24ZFFZSX7ILE6JGM.html?outputType\u003damp\u0026utm_source\u003dupday\u0026utm_medium\u003dreferral",
            "client_id": "59VD9fg/2RVO1jSDxOwfxw\u003d\u003d",
            "time_usec": 1607593733981438
}]
```

and if I'm reading your question correctly, it's better off parsing your Source Data as JSON directly, and grab the URL with the 'url' key.

```
with open ('history.json','r') as history:
    json_data = history.read()
    data = json.loads(json_data)

    for k, v in data.items():  #because now your Source data is a dictionary
        for block in v:        #because v is the list of textblocks
            print("scraping " + block["url"] + "...")
```

Comment: first and all thank you very mutch for your help, but now I get a different error message:File "/home/user/Dokumente/foo Exception get handled.py", line
22, in <module>
     print("scraping " + json_data["url"] + "...")
KeyError: 'url'

I tried to avoid this problem with try and except, but that did not work either, do you maybe have an Idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: @Reijarmo how does your data look like now? You faced this problem because you don't have the 'url' key in your Source Data.

Comment: thank you so mutch for your ongoing support.  the Source data is a .json file (the one you get, when you safe a back up from your google Account.  It contains hundred of textblock like the one above (source data). I tried to solve this problem with  
 `try:
        json_data=json.load(history)
        print("scraping " + json_data["url"] + "...")
    except KeyError:
        pass
        html = getHtml (json_data)`  then the code starts processing some site, but get a hell  of Errors because of to mutch exceptions. When I got your question wrong, I am very sorry for wasting your time

Comment: @Reijarmo okay, the code I showed is reading just one block. Since you mention it contains many blocks, I assume it is an array of blocks? If that's the case you will need to iterate through it, meaning you need to use a for loop.

Comment: ahh sorry there was a Misunderstandig, I am Sorry @blessthefrey. Yes, it is an array of blocks, I tried to implement the loop, but it just creates many json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: expecting value.  (the “loop“  i try to use at the moment:  `with open('urls.json') as history:
    for i, line in enumerate(history.readlines()):
        try:
            json_data=json.load(history)
            print("scraping " + json_data["url"] + "...")
        except KeyError:
            pass`

Comment: @Reijarmo I have modified my code, you can try to see if it works for you now.

Comment: thank you for your help now I get a new error: line 25, in <module> print("scraping " + block["url"] + "...") TypeError: string indices must be integers, also i edit the first post with the new code –

Comment: @Reijarmo I have added sample data that I tried, can you see if its the same. It should work.

Comment: I added the first 34 lines of the source file as reference.  I tried your code and get a rather strange error: No connection adapters were found for '[{\n            "page_transition": "LINK",\n            "title": "Niedersachsen Corona-Lockerungen für Silvester zurück",\n            "url": "h    "time_usec": 1607593733981438\n}]\n\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
Resarch tells me such things  maybe happens because of some hidden charakters in the url, but it cant be, because same url works for you, otherwise i would try a try command. I am very sorry for all the trouble